# Can we use spring jdbctemplate queryForObject for update operations as well?

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I understood like spring jdbcTemplate - queryForObject is only for read operation against DB. But if we supply any update query, that also works fine which returns the updated object as well. So, is it good approach to use? Pls check my code snippet below

```
Employee employee = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(updateQuery, params,
                new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Employee>(Employee.class));
```

Please add your suggestions

Comment: I would rather not do that, from my point of view it is always better to separate read and write operations to have a more maintainable code. In the future if you add new properties you would be forced to edit all your queries and if you separate read and writes that will not be the case.

Comment: @karelss, we don't need to write any seperate query for read operation. It simply returns the whole object.